# How to avoid word break in exam class?

Tags: formatting, pdftex, line-breaking, page-breaking, exam

I'm using exam class to represent questions, sample question in exam class is mentioned below:

```
\question \textbf{A body is moving with velocity 30 m/s towards east. After 10 seconds its velocity becomes 40 m/s towards north. The average acceleration of the body is }
 \rule{1cm}{0pt} \newline \begin{minipage}{0.98\linewidth}
\begin{choices}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\choice \textbf{5 $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{m/{s^2} }$ }
  \choice \textbf{1\ $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{m/{s^2} }$ }
 \end{multicols} \begin{multicols}{2}  \choice \textbf{7\ $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{m/{s^2} }$ }
  \choice \textbf{$\displaystyle \boldsymbol{\sqrt 7  }$ \ $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{m/{s^2} }$ }

\end{multicols}
\end{choices}
\end{minipage}
```

It gives output as [image]

Is there any way to avoid word breaks on a line; In question above word "towards" and "becomes" must go to next line as there is less space to accommodate them in a given line?

Kindly advise?

Comment: `raggedright` comes to mind. Is that what you alre looking for?

Comment: From an educational point of view: Please do it properly. **30 m** is not the same as *30 m*, is not the same as 30 m.  Package `siunitx` can help you to properly typeset values and units. Please read some introductory material on mathematical and physical typesetting. If the teachers aren't trained properly, the students won't be either.

Comment: I tried to test your example. If i add what is needed to even compile the snippet, i see a completely different output.

Answer (score 3):

A cw-answer. The way I would do it. No bold questions, no bold answers.

I am not used to the `exam` class. I use the exam related packages by C. Niederberger and the `siunitx` package by JAW.

The `exsheets` documentation shows *various* ways to customize the questions to own needs.

The result is something readable.

[image: pawanmudeExamRagged]

```
\documentclass[a5paper
]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
headings=runin,
headings-format=\large\bfseries
}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{exsheets-exercise-name}{}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{%
    counter-format=(tsk),label-width=4ex 
}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\speed}{\meter\per\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\accel}{\meter\per\second\squared}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
    A body is moving with velocity \SI{30}{\speed} towards east. After \SI{10}{\second} its
    velocity becomes \SI{40}{\speed} towards north. The average acceleration of the body is
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task \SI{5}{\accel} \task \SI{1}{\accel}
        \task \SI{7}{\accel} \task $\sqrt{7}$\,\si{\accel}
    \end{tasks}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```